# How can I do snapshot testing?

Tags: go

Does [testing](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/) package support snapshot testing?

Here is my case:

```golang
package main

import (
  "bytes"
  "fmt"
  "html/template"
)

func main() {
  query := `
    INSERT INTO "ADGROUP_PERFORMANCE_REPORT" (
      {{.columnPrefix}}_adgroup_id, 
      {{.columnPrefix}}_adgroup_nme, 
      {{.columnPrefix}}_adgroup_status, 
      {{.columnPrefix}}_campaign_id, 
      {{.columnPrefix}}_campaign_nme, 
      {{.columnPrefix}}_campaign_status, 
      {{.columnPrefix}}_clicks, 
      {{.columnPrefix}}_impressions, 
      {{.columnPrefix}}_ctr, 
      {{.columnPrefix}}_average_cpc, 
      {{.columnPrefix}}_cost, 
      {{.columnPrefix}}_conversions, 
      {{.columnPrefix}}_average_position, 
      {{.columnPrefix}}_device, 
      google_adwords_client_customer_id
    ) VALUES
  `
  vars := make(map[string]interface{})
  vars["columnPrefix"] = "adgroup_performance_report"
  result := processString(query, vars)
  fmt.Printf("result=%s\n", result)
}

func process(t *template.Template, vars interface{}) string {
  var tmplBytes bytes.Buffer
  err := t.Execute(&tmplBytes, vars)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  return tmplBytes.String()
}

func processString(str string, vars interface{}) string {
  tmpl, err := template.New("tmpl").Parse(str)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  return process(tmpl, vars)
}
```

Now I am going to write unit test for it, I would like use snapshot testing to test the structure of the SQL query string processed by `html/template` pkg.

Here is the output in the stdout:

```sh
result=
    INSERT INTO "ADGROUP_PERFORMANCE_REPORT" (
      adgroup_performance_report_adgroup_id, 
      adgroup_performance_report_adgroup_nme, 
      adgroup_performance_report_adgroup_status, 
      adgroup_performance_report_campaign_id, 
      adgroup_performance_report_campaign_nme, 
      adgroup_performance_report_campaign_status, 
      adgroup_performance_report_clicks, 
      adgroup_performance_report_impressions, 
      adgroup_performance_report_ctr, 
      adgroup_performance_report_average_cpc, 
      adgroup_performance_report_cost, 
      adgroup_performance_report_conversions, 
      adgroup_performance_report_average_position, 
      adgroup_performance_report_device, 
      google_adwords_client_customer_id
    ) VALUES
```

I don't want to write this expected value duplicately in unit test file and assert it. I prefer using snapshot testing and it will generate a snapshot file. Something like [jestjs snapshot-testing](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the `testing` Package does not support something like this out of the box. There is a pattern for Go that you can utilise called "Golden file testing". The convention is to store testdata in a `testdata` folder alongside your test. In this case you would store the rendered template in a so called "golden file". The test itself provides an `update` flag to write out the latest version (so that you don't have to manually maintain the output):

```
var update = flag.Bool("update", false, "update .golden files")
func TestProcessString(t *testing.T) {
  vars := make(map[string]interface{})
  vars["columnPrefix"] = "adgroup_performance_report"
  actual := processString(query, vars)
  golden := filepath.Join(“testdata”, ”performance_report.golden”)
  if *update {
    ioutil.WriteFile(golden, actual, 0644)
  }
  expected, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(golden)

  if !bytes.Equal(actual, expected) {
    t.Fatalf("Output did not match, expected %v, recieved %v, expected, actual)
  }
}
```

A nice example of this pattern can be found in the `gofmt` source code: https://golang.org/src/cmd/gofmt/gofmt_test.go

Comment: Very helpful. But the source code of `gofmt_test.go` is a little complex. Snapshot testing feature should be added to `testing` package so that developer can use it out of the box.

Comment: @slideshowp2: You're welcome to propose that on the Go issue tracker, but I doubt it will be accepted, as Go has a philosophy of not hiding complexity. And this can be easily supported by a third-party library, such as [this one](https://gitlab.com/flimzy/testy) which I wrote, which takes a slightly different approach, but same concept.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably too late as an answer, but I have been working on a snapshot testing library for Golang that is "like" jest toMatchSnapshot.

I believe it matches exactly your use case, how to test long strings that you don't want to keep that string on or unit tests.

It would be as simple as and also provides a nice diff view

```
func TestExample(t *testing.T) {

 snaps.MatchSnapshot(t ,processString(query, vars))

}
```

You can have a look [go-snaps](https://github.com/gkampitakis/go-snaps).